# How do you Migrate AWS Workspace to Azure VDI ? is this possible and how

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, migration, workspace, vdi

I have several Machines on AWS Workspace and would like to move them to Azure Vdi, Is there a tool? and way to do that migration smoothly? what are the possibilities?

I know Azure Migrate is for EC2 migration but I think the workspace is different and Just want to know if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot migrate from Amazon Workspaces to Azure or any other Cloud Provider. If you are looking at migrating your data from Amazon Workspaces, then the only option is to copy them into EFS so it can be extracted. All the root and user volumes are managed by AWS so no direct control.

Comment: Many Thanks, so only user data and the disk-like data disk attached can be copied only not the os image?